# Unable to access the extjs application after upgraded from 4.1 to 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

Recently I have upgraded my extjs application from 4.1 to 4.2. The project successfully upgraded and was able to see it in architect. But while previewing the app is not getting loaded into the browser.

Please help.

Thank much.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what is the problem for this question with such minute information. However, to answer your question via a shortcut.. Open your application via **Google Chrome** browser and press **Ctrl+Shift+I** to Open **Developer Tools** , Select the **Console Tab** to see the exact problem. You will see what is stopping your application from running.

Comment: I have checked it with Firebug, there was no error. The console was clear. I think the problem is with migration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
ExtJs 4.2 has a different directory structure.

You didn't mention if you changed the directory structure to that recommended by Sencha,
but it worked for me.
Look at [2.Application structure](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/getting_started).
Also remember to change the index.html file to reflect changes of the structure (maybe ExtJs isn't called at all).